# VB.net Select statement where data is equal to today

Tags: sql, vb.net, tableadapter

i have a tableadapter called msg

```
id|text|time
1 |jdhh|3/18/2019 03:32:55
1 |jffh|3/18/2019 03:32:55
1 |jdeh|3/17/2019 03:35:55
1 |sshh|3/16/2019 04:30:55
```

i want to return text and id from this table where date is today

my query is : `"SELECT id, text from msg where time = today()"`

but it doesn't return any rows because the date format includes time as well in database  , so how to make it return rows with same date as today

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: i'm using SDF database

Comment: SDF is not a database, it is a file format associated with SQL Server CE.  If that is what you are using, then tag appropriately.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Why does it matter what database when she is retrieving records from a TableAdapter?

Comment: @Mary . . . Is `today()` replaced in the VB code?

Comment: @GordonLinoff No, I didn't realize that TableAdapters call the database on each Select query. I got burned many years ago with "Write a CRUD app with 5 lines of code" and I never used components and generated code again.

Comment: @Mary . . . Well, if it not replaced in the VB code, then it needs to be supported by the underlying database.  And `today()` is not a common function.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Of course, thank you. I was mentally equating a TableAdapter with a DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in SQL Server CE:

```
SELECT id, text
FROM msg 
WHERE CONVERT(char(10), time, 120) = CONVERT(char(10), GETDATE(), 120);
```

Comment: it doesn't work  , it says the specific data type is not valid

Answer (score 0):

this is an option

```
SELECT id, text
FROM msg 
WHERE year(time) = year(GETDATE())
and month(time) = month(GETDATE())
and day(time) = day(GETDATE());
```

alternatively, pass in two datetimes on for 00:00 and the other for 23:59

```
SELECT id, text
FROM msg 
WHERE time >= @begintime
and time <= @emdtime;
```